# Changing Color in Coordinate Plot in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to change the color in alternates of red and blue. So far I only have:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
  % Axes
 \draw [-latex] (-1,0) -- (12,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
 \draw [-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,6.5) node [above] {$y$};
  % Origin
 \node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};
 % Points
 \coordinate (start) at (1,1.5);
 \coordinate (1) at (3,.5);
 \coordinate (2) at (5.5,4.5);
 \coordinate (3) at (7.5,2.75);
 \coordinate (end) at (9,6);
 % Plot
 \draw [red,thick,-] (start) to[out=-30,in=180] (1) to[out=0,in=180]
  (2) to[out=0,in=110] (3) to[out=45,in=225] (end);

 % show the points

 \foreach \n in {start,1,2,3,end} \fill [black] (\n)
   circle (2pt) node [below] {}; 

  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Any advice how to make the color alternative between red and blue with one color between each point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some improvements in the code.

- `standalone` class to produce a single draw.
- You can `scope` the lines to set the line width once.
- You don't need to insert `node` in the bullets.
- `black` is the default color, don't need to pass it to `fill`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Axes
\draw [-latex] (-1,0) -- (12,0) node (xaxis) [below] {$x$};
\draw [-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,6.5) node [left] {$y$};

% Origin
\node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};

% Points
\coordinate (start) at (1,1.5);
\coordinate (1) at (3,.5);
\coordinate (2) at (5.5,4.5);
\coordinate (3) at (7.5,2.75);
\coordinate (end) at (9,6);

% Plot
\begin{scope}[thick]
\draw [red]         (start) to[out=-30,in=180] (1);
\draw [red!60!blue] (1)     to[out=0,in=180]   (2);
\draw [red!30!blue] (2)     to[out=0,in=110]   (3);
\draw [blue]        (3)     to[out=45,in=225]  (end);
\end{scope}

% show the points
\foreach \n in {start,1,2,3,end}{%
  \fill (\n) circle (2pt); 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you broke it up in parts and then redefined the color. Thanks, for some reason I kept thinking that it wasn't possible.

Comment: @MathScholar, welcomed.